# Image resize with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a question about the image resizing in CSS.

I have a 1920x1080 image.

This image should be automatically resized to fit on any screen, however I am unable to do this.

Example of what I want [here](http://www.dadaabstories.org/)

At the top, a video start to play, that's how I want you to be my page, but instead of a video, the picture.

My HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="slides">
<ul>
    <li><img src="_img/img1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="_img/img2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="_img/img3.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="_img/img4.jpg"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

All the images inside the div called `slides` should fit in any screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should insert meta `viewport` on your `head`, like this

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

then here is a snippet of how you could make this work.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
#slides img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block /*fix inline image small gap*/
}

/*larger devices than the size of image */
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  #slides img {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slides">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, just another question, I'm starting to do a Slideshow using jQuery, so the page should show only 1 image per time. How can I do that?

Comment: You should then ask another question posting relevant code instead. IMHO. Otherwise this question would get  a lot confused. But there is a lot of jQuery SlideShows online.

Comment: I can post only once every 90 minutes T-T. Is there anyway to show only 1 image per time using CSS?

Comment: [here](http://codepen.io/antoniskamamis/pen/hjBrE) is a pure CSS example, from a quick google search "*Pure CSS Slideshow*"

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `<img>` to have a `width` property of 100%, which would limit the image width to the window's width.

```
<li><img src="_img/img1.jpg" width="100%"></li>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n3uwfjLz/)

#### CSS

```
li > img {
width:100%;
}
```

To optimize for mobile users, you can also set the [viewport as the device width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mobile%2FViewport_meta_tag), like so:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Comment: Works,  just another question, I'm starting to do a Slideshow using jQuery, so the page should show only 1 image per time. How can I do that?

Comment: Flex Slider is a good jQuery plugin for slideshows: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: `width` in HTML tag  is bad practice, instead use CSS property

Comment: Edited to include CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You should add to your CSS:

```
#slides img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

This make the images fit the width of the container and keeping the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a background for `li` instead the `img` in this way:

```
<body>
<div id="slides">
<ul>
    <li id="img1"></li>
    <li id="img2"></li>
    <li id="img3"></li>
    <li id="img4"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

then you just set the global background property (CSS):

```
#slides li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and set the single background images individually (CSS)

```
#img1 {
    background: url(the_url_1.jpg);
}
#img2 {
    background: url(the_url_2.jpg);
}
```

the background-size property do the magic:

- if you set it as `cover` you scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area;
- if you set it as `contain` you scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area;